# How to create a react-redux app with node server as backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I am trying to create a react-redux app using node server as backend. Is it possible to make the node server serve the react-redux app instead of running react-redux using dev server a=in one port and node on another port?

Need some idea to start with. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an useful doc for redux SSR setup. This helps avoiding running client and server at two ports.

[Redux SSR](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. it is

you can serve you react app on '/'
and listen for API request in another route
so you don't have separate codebase for the react app and the api backend code

You can use express to serve the react app on a particular route
i.e my-app.com/

then serve backend related content on another route

i.e
my-app.com/api

so when a request is made to my-app.com/ express serves express serves backend resource or API

Comment: @nadeshoki-- In this case, do i need to run two servers? One for serving react and other for node.js?

Comment: No there's no need just one

Comment: @nadeshoki-- Do you mean to say, i can make node.js to serve my react app on one route and other APIs on different routes?

Comment: Yes thats what i meant

Comment: @nadeshoki-- Also, could you please give me any reference where I can find an example of such setup..

Comment: @nadeshoki-- If this solution also works for a react-redux app?

Comment: @nadeshoki-- I am not finding how do i serve a react app from express server. Do you have any reference?

Comment: I solved this out in my code couldnt get any reference I was searching that for a while when u asked

Comment: @nadeshoki-- Anyway! Thanks.. I will find out something.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps I take when creating an express/react app together. I'll create a server and a client directory. The client dir is created with create-react-app and the server can be created via express-generator for example. My project dir (the one that contains both of them) is basically just glue that melds the two together. In the client app, I'll add `proxy:localhost:3001` (or whatever port your express api is running) and I use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run both servers (client and server - as client is being run by webpack-dev-server) at the same time. They run as separate servers during development, but when I make an api call, it's as if I'm making it directly to the express server itself.

The only other thing to worry about is deploying the application. You can use the build command that comes with create-react-app and copy that over to the public directory in your express application that is served up via express.static.

Here's a quick example to take a look at:
https://github.com/overthemike/heroku-skeleton

Comment: S-- Thanks, however, i did prefer nadeshoki's suggestion, as I can avoid using two dev servers during development. Also, i found a similar solution in redux docs itself.